# Java try with resources and `AutoCloseable` interface

Tags: java, with-statement, try-with-resources

I am looking for a Java equivalent for python's `with` statement, and I read about implementing the `AutoCloseable` interface and using try with resources.

In python, the context manager (`with` statement) uses two methods: `__enter__` and `__exit__`, but in Java, the try with resources block uses only `close`, which is the equivalent of `__exit__`.

Is there an equivalent for the `__enter__` method, in order to perform a certain method automatically when entering the try with resources block, and not only when the block is over?

Comment: You have code block inside `try (....) {` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: You're likely to do something like `try (YourClass x = new YourClass())` so I'd say the constructor is the equivalent of the `__enter__` method.

Answer (score 6):

The equivalent is basically whatever you are calling in the `try` to get an instance of your `AutoCloseable`. This could be a constructor like:

```
try (MyClass obj = new MyClass()) { …
```

Where the class having such a constructor looks like:

```
public class MyClass implements AutoCloseable {
    public MyClass() {
        // do "enter" things...
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // close resources
    }
}
```

Depending on what you need "enter" to do, you might instead prefer a static producer for your class, which would look like this:

```
try (MyClass obj = MyClass.getInstance(someProperties)) { …
```

Then your class might look something like this:

```
public class MyClass implements AutoCloseable {
    private MyClass() {
        // instantiate members
    }

    public static MyClass getInstance(Properties config) {
        // you could implement a singleton pattern or something instead, for example
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        // read properties...
        // do "enter" things...
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // close resources
    }
}
```

You could even call a factory or builder pattern in the `try` to produce your `AutoCloseable`. It all depends on your design and what you need the instance to do on "enter".

Comment: "do "enter" things..." but also remember to clean up in the case that those enter things fail.

Comment: What about if I don't want the constructor to be the `__enter__` method, since I want to also be able to create an object without performing the "enter" method, and I want it to be called only if the object is created inside the `try(...)`?

Comment: Good Answer. I suggest adding the `close` method to both `MyClass` samples for consistency and clarity.

Comment: @Dani A pattern I'd suggest is to not have your class be AutoCloseable at all in that case, but instead have a method that returns an AutoCloseable that's a nested class (probably with a private constructor): `new MyFoo().asAutoCloseable()`. That method then handles the `__enter__` code. You could also do a static method as this answer suggests, but making it be a new method nicely separates the AutoCloseable use cases from the class's other use cases.